# Has there ever been a TV show VHS/DVD/bluray/4K release in THX?

Tags: cinema-sound

I'm wondering. We know movies get THX remasters all the time. But what about TV shows? Has there ever been a TV show release in THX?

Answer (score 1):

You're unlikely to see a "THX release" on any consumer-grade media, because THX is not a standard that consumer-grade equipment can meet.

Per wikipedia:

> [The THX system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/THX) is not a recording technology and it does not specify a sound recording format: all sound formats, whether digital (Dolby Digital, DTS, SDDS) or analog (Dolby Stereo, Ultra Stereo), can be "shown in THX". THX is a quality assurance system. THX-certified theaters provide a high-quality, predictable playback environment to ensure that any film soundtrack mixed in THX will sound as near as possible to the intentions of the mixing engineer.

In effect, being certified for THX requires the recording equipment, the production equipment, and the presentation equipment to meet certain standards. A "THX release" is something almost nobody would have a use for.